# Аномально ужасная работа юнити со звуками

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио

Обрыскал все интернеты, нигде ответа не нашел. Дело в том, что юнити(2019.3.15f) неадекватно работает со звуками. Если на сцене висит любой звук, даже если его размер не превышает 50кб, сцена грузится минут 5. Без звука загрузка почти мгновенна. Даже когда я в инспекторе выбираю звуковой файл, юнька начинает люто тормозить. Самое интересное, что при этом, мой компьютер не нагружается.

Пробовал конвертировать mp3 в ogg, включал флажок LoadInBackground - эффекта 0.

Нужен ваш совет, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [Scene Loading Very Slow - Sometimes](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1479194/scene-loading-very-slow-sometimes.html)

Comment: @tym32167 просто ссылки нельзя кидать вроде как

Comment: @Methorn почему вы так решили?

Comment: @Methorn в ответ - не рекомендуется. А это комментарии.